# What are some examples of amicable inter-state border dispute resolution?

Tags: armed-conflict, territorial-dispute

What are some examples of amicable inter-state border dispute resolution?
By *state*, I mean a state as in US states like Texas, California, etc. Or, [Assam, Mizoram](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-india-57969157) in India.

What comes in my mind are both states sacrificing that land for national purpose, common sharing of that area, etc. I would love some real life examples.

Comment: I promise a bounty too to the good answerer.

Answer (score 1):

[Ellis Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellis_Island) of historical fame was originally New York land. However, due to some unusual clauses of the original New York - New Jersey border, the reclaimed (i.e. expanded) island was ruled to be New Jersey land in 1998 by the Supreme Court case *[New Jersey v. New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Jersey_v._New_York)*. See below for NY territory in green, NJ in light green.

[image: Ellis Island]

The Wikipedia page [mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellis_Island#State_sovereignty_dispute) no violence before the court ruling.